# How to re-install a modified R package

Tags: r, github, package

Technically I have 2 probs when I tried to install a package:
1. The package can be installed normally from github by `devtools::install_github`, however, when I download the zip file and try to manually install it from R or RStudio, I failed. The package seems can't be installed in this way. So could somebody explain that.
2. I tried to fix some bugs by modifying the `.r` source codes in `R` directory of the package unzipped folder. Then I think I need to re-compile/re-construct the package. Could some one give me a tutorial to do that.
IOS: Windows10, 64bit; R and Rtools are both the newest.
For prob1, here is the screen capture:
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: If uninstalling and reinstalling from source doesn't solve problem #1 then please post the code and the download link for the package to make it reproducible, along with the error message

Comment: The github link is [link](https://github.com/snoweye/remoter). No error message appears. The installation process is done normally, but I can't `library` the package, and `R` reports `no such package`. When I check the `lib.loc`, only a folder `remoter-master` is built but the package is not installed correctly actually.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close R and RStudio (if applicable) and uninstall the package manually by deleting its folder from your file system
2. For your 2nd problem after following #1 you can reinstall it by installing from source:

   ```
   install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")
   ```

Please confirm that these worked for you or let me know if not.